# Update a Table Field to its Value Plus a Constant on MYSQL w/o PHP

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sum

I would like to perform an `UPDATE` in `MYSQL` in which I take a field value, add a constant and save the new value in the same field.

Let's assume that we have a column called `OldValue` in a table called `aTable`.

Pseudocode could be:

```
UPDATE aTable SET OldValue = OldValue + 220 WHERE someField = someValue
```

Do you have any idea on how I could do that? I would like to use a single query (on some administration panel) without making a `php` script.  (Of course, in that case the answer is quite simple.)

Comment: what about your code? it will work. wat data type is `oldvalue`?

Comment: sometimes pseudo code is not as pseudo as you think ;)

Comment: What's the problem? Do you want update all rows or only with `someField = someValue`?

Comment: did you try to execute the code?

Comment: Miracle.. it worked... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code will work.

[See it working in SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a26b/1).

I used your exact query verbatim, except for substituting a real value for "someValue".

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example using Pseudocode from original question itself.

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `field1` = `field1` - 18, `field2` = `field2` + 16 WHERE n_id IN (111,222,333) OR form IN ('Digital Editing','Studio Room') AND location_id LIKE ('%home-page10%')
```