# adding variable to column in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Simple question but can't seem to find the answer to it. I have a table in SQL. I'm running an SQL query from within a php file where I want to add the variable `$num` to the value already in the table and store it there. So if my table contains 1000 and `$num` is 4000 the new value in the table should be 5000. Would it be `UPDATE table SET column = column + '$num'`?

Comment: yes, and why not just try  it?

Comment: yes it would be like that only

Comment: Thanks guys, @juergend just wanted to make sure so that I don't mess up my test data with nonsense values

Comment: Please keep in mind this will update every record in your table.

Comment: @Don'tPanic is correct

Comment: Make sure you always test on a test system and not on production.

Comment: @mankee if your afraid of messing up data :) begin transaction! and rollback :D

Comment: @Don'tPanic that's my intention. I'm passing a string of `id,value` pairs, breaking it up using explode and then updating each id with the column + value. Didn't want to include that unnecessary info in the question tho

Comment: Sounds good, just thought it was worth mentioning just in case. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a Table Field to its Value Plus a Constant on MYSQL w/o PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605924/update-a-table-field-to-its-value-plus-a-constant-on-mysql-w-o-php)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would work. I would also make sure you have a `WHERE` clause in there as well - otherwise you will update the entire table.

For example, if you only wanted to update the table where your column is some value it would be:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = column + '$num'
WHERE column = 'someValue'
```